# ASP.NET triggering update panel refresh from code behind

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, postback

I have 2 update panels on my ASP.NET page (updatepanel1 and updatepanel2). I want to trigger the updatepanel2 to refresh/update from updatepanel1 in the code behind, so in the updatepanel1_Load event I will make a call to updatepanel2.Update().

But I need a way to check (in updatepanel2_Load) if the asynchronous postback was caused by this call in updatepanel1_Load or not. Is there a way to check if the call/postback trigger came from updatepanel1?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

would it be good for you to update both update panels when clicking one of them?

then you should use triggers:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
              //your html
        </ContentTemplate>

        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="updatePnl_SECOND" /> 
        </Triggers> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePnl_SECOND" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
              //your html
        </ContentTemplate>    
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the case above, if user clicks something that postbacks from updatePnl_SECOND the updatePnl will also update.

Does that help you?

Comment: You'll need `UpdateMode="Conditional"` in order to use `Triggers`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It's not really what I'm looking for though..  because in my updatepanel1_Load event I have a block of code which I want to execute _before_  the second update panel begins to update.  So at the moment I have a block of code in updatepanel1_Load followed by a call to updatepanel2.Update() ..   it's just I want a way to test if the call came from updatepanel1 in updatepanel2_Load. do you know if something like that is possible? thanks